# Understanding char array memory allocation

Tags: c++

I seem to get the same result with thees two snippets. I'm simply a bit confused how they both could work and I'm hoping for some insights to why that is.

1. Are both arrays stored the same way in memory?
2. Are they stored on the hype?
3. Do I need to use `delete[]`?

---

`std::ifstream file`

```
char buffer[bufferSize];
file->read(buffer, bufferSize);
```

**VS**

```
char * buffer = new char[bufferSize];
file->read(buffer, bufferSize);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first declaration of `buffer` creates a statically sized buffer on the stack: for this declaration to work, `bufferSize` has to be a compile-time constant! Well, some compilers do have an extension to implement C's variable length arrays in C++, too, but that is not portable (at least, not yet: there is some discussion on creating a similar feature in C++, too).

The second definition of `buffer` allocates the array on the heap using memory allocation. Unless you also `delete[]` the buffer, you actually have a memory leak, i.e., you probably want to use something like

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[bufferSize]);
file->read(buffer.get(), bufferSize);
```

Both of the original code snippets work because arrays decay into pointers to their first element on the first opportunity they get. This behavior is inherited from C.

The main difference between both approaches is that stack allocation is fast but the stack size tends to be rather limited (e.g., by default just 48kB on some systems) while allocating memory on the heap tends to be a bit slower but large buffers are normally not a problem. Stack-allocated memory is released when the function is exited while heap-allocated memory needs to be `delete[]`d in some form.

To answer the questions you posted after I had mostly typed the response above:

1. No: the first is on the stack, the second is on the heap.
2. No: the first is on the stack, the second is on the heap.
3. Depends: no if the object is on the stack, yes, if the object is on the heap.

Comment: howcome you advocate `unique_ptr` instead of `vector` ?

Comment: So the stack has a memory limitation, didn't know that. Thought it only had to do with what scope it existed in. 48kb is far from what I need. The binary file I'm reading could be 100 times bigger then that. I guess I need to store on the heap then. Is there an error or exception that is thrown when the stack has flooded?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: How does `std::vector` release an array allocated on the heap? :-) More seriously, if you just need a dynamically sized local array, `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` is actually a reasonable option although I'd personally probably just use an `std::vector<T>` if I need an array.

Comment: @ErikLandvall: the stack on most machines is bigger than 48kB. A typical default size seems to be 2MB. However, 48kB is the default size of a pthreads created thread on AIX systems (at least, on some of those I'm using).

Comment: @DietmarKühl Ok, but the heap is only limited by the machines RAM?

Comment: @ErikLandvall: It is - complicated... The heap may be bigger than the machine's RAM as most systems to use disk to store unused memory pages. It may also be smaller, e.g., if other processes allocate lots of memory. ... and whether you can allocate a large chunk of memory depends on how the memory currently looks like and probably how many bits pointers use. If memory is fragmented by earlier allocations of small objects, there may also be no big chunk of memory.

Answer (score 2):

1. nope, first variant uses stack, second one - heap
2. see 1)
3. for the second variant only